# Can anyone access what is inside Assests folder?

Tags: android, security, android-assets

I want to develop an application for some company. The application is mainly a search tool in a specific database.

I have two ways to develop this application:

1. Include the DB file into the `assest` folder and use it.
2. search using API. (My search tool has an API. And you can search the DB using the browser).

I prefer the first option. The problem is my customer want their DB files to not be accessible by unauthorized parties. They are very serious about this issue.

If I developed the app using the first option:

1. can anyone retrieve the DB data from the .apk file or from anywhere else ?
2. Is the DB file NOT secure if I put it into the `assest` folder ?

If the answers are YES, then can I avoid making end-user use the internet to search in my tool? Can I avoid using option 2? i.e. Is there any secure way to include the DB without worrying about the security issue I mentioned ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, If you have a .db file or any other file in your `asset directory` of .apk file then anyone can `access it by unpacking the .apk file`.

But If you ask about other application then its not access your application's .db file which is private to your package.

Comment: The user can also easily browse the contents of an app's resources resources on a rooted device. So I'd suggest not putting any sensitive information there, especially if it's enencrypted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You clarified some issues to me.

Comment: Can you say something about my 2nd part of the question? `Is there any secure way to include the DB without worrying about the security issue?`.

Comment: @iturki - If you put the .db file in your application's internal storage then no-one access your database file, accept in rooted device. So I think use encrypted file and keep the key for decryption in your application's shared preference in private mode. and whenever you want to use decrypt it then use it. Thanks.

Comment: The encrypt-decrypt approach seems to be the only option I have. Thanks dude.