# Is it possible to embed (without download) a PDF file in a one view bilingual Android app?

Tags: android, localization, internationalization, pdf-viewer

Does anyone know if the following project is achievable for an Android app:

- One view only
- PDF file embedded
- PDF file read into the app (not into Adobe Acrobat)
- PDF file cannot be downloaded into the user's Android device
- Only zooming page needed (and support of the internal PDF's hyperlinks)
- Bilingual / the PDF file being different according to the user's personal language settings

That project is the twin one of a very simple bilingual iOS App consisting of a PDF file embedded in a UIWebview.

I searched a lot on the subject, and I can't really tell if that twin project is achievable. If so, would there be an example of it somewhere ?

Thanks very much !

Comment: @Durairaj P mentioned using the Assets folder, which I think would be the way to go for your situation.  However, based on your "PDF file cannot be downloaded into the user's Android device" criteria, I wanted to offer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816792/can-anyone-access-what-is-inside-assests-folder  If there are security reasons for not wanting the user to download the .PDF file, there's not much you can do to keep someone with a little know-how from getting access to it or any of your resources, data, or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the file in Assets directory and you can use Asset Manager to access the file.

```
 AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        try {
            InputStream tinstr = assetManager.open("myjpg.pdf");
            mDefaultThumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream (tinstr);
            tinstr.close ();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace ();
        }
```

Comment: - So, if the PDF file is put into the Assets directory, it will not be automatically downloaded into the user's Android device so that the user will not see the PDF file on his device; but the file could be retrieved with a little effort and knowledge. Is that true ?

Comment: The files placed in Assets directory will be bundled with the APK and will be available in the device when the user installs the application

Comment: Therefore, in an Android app, there is no way of simply displaying a PDF file without permitting the user to get the file. Thanks very much for your answers. I'll just abandon the project - for now.